# Does a broken chord, alternating up and down intervals, have a name?

Tags: theory, chords, terminology, arpeggios

[image: Image of alternative descending ascending G-C-E-G-C-E-G-C]

It's like an arpeggio but doesn't go straight up or straight down. I want to call it a non-linear arpeggio but I completely made that up. So is there a name for the pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it's a broken chord. Arpeggios generally are played straight up and down, broken chords are the same notes, but played in staggered manner. ABRSM use 'broken chords' in their early piano exams rather than 'arpeggios'.

Comment: An arpeggio is a broken chord, but a broken chord need not be an arpeggio.

Comment: I was going to quote that!